# Android Hide Sliding Drawer After Some Time

Tags: java, android, timer, timertask

I have a slidingdrawer in my activity, i open sliding drawer on swipe gesture from bottom to top what i want is to close that opened drawer after some second or delay let say after 5 seconds. How can i do that?

```
private class GestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
   SlidingDrawer drawer;
   Timer timer;

   public GestureDetector(SlidingDrawer drawer) {
        this.drawer = drawer;
        timer = new Timer();
   }

   TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

       @Override
       public void run() {
         closeSlider();
       }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        if(e1.getY() > e2.getY()) {         
             this.drawer.animateOpen(); 
             timer.scheduleAtFixedRate( timerTask , 0, 3000);           
         } else {                 
            //this.drawer.animateClose();
         }                        
    }

       public void closeSlider() {
            this.drawer.animateClose();
         }
   }

   //i call it on activity onCreate()
   SlidingDrawer slidingDrawer = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.slidingDrawer);
   new GestureDetector(slidingDrawer);
```

Thanking you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

   @Override
        public void run() {
        // TODO call closeSlider method here.

        }
}, 5000);
```